# How to block get requests from my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, request, block, antimalware

I have a wordpress site. This site has an unwanted code and redirecting to a spam site on page load. I want to block some GET request because malware getting unwanted code from spam site. I can manually block request from chrome developer tools but i want to block it in htaccess file.

Thanks

Comment: If your site is infected you should take it offline NOW. Period.

Comment: Then you can either reinstall from a backup or _try_ to remove the infected part, though that typically is much more difficult.

Comment: Either way there is no sense in trying to fix symptoms. You need to cure the cause.